# Does <META http-equiv=Pragma content=no-cache> affect XMLHttpRequest's?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I am creating a html page which will be hosted in an iFrame.

In the main `<head>` (page hosting iFrame) I just discovered the follownig meta tags:

```
<META http-equiv=Pragma content=no-cache>
<META http-equiv=Cache-Control content=no-cache,no-store,max-age =0>
<META http-equiv=Expires content=-1>
```

What I want to know, is that will this affect any of my `XMLHTTPRequests` that I am making? I am storing the `XMLHTTPRequest.response` as a blob, and then using this blob as the `src` for `<video>` and `<audio>` etc.

**Psuedo code:**

```
1. XMLHTTPRequest to blob
2. store blob in var
3. use var as video src
```

---

I tested this from within the iFrame and the blobs / video load as expected and play fine, so what do those meta tags do? Because I was under the impression that blobs went into the browser cache?

**Note:** I checked the browser's (chrome) network log for the blob and it says *(from disk cache)*.

Comment: The meta tags only affect how the page itself is cached, not any of its resources (including your iframe). Even if they did, that wouldn’t break anything; whether blobs work has nothing to do with cache headers.

Comment: @Ryan interesting, well that is very good news then! Thank you. Long live the blobs.